# echo displaying 1 before the correct text

Tags: php

Everything else is working correctly when I am registering a user(they are added to database and activation email is sent) however the text that I am returning from my "echo" to say 'thanks for registering' includes a 1 infront of it and I can't for the life of me work out why as I am doing the same thing in other places and it is working correctly, below is my code:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $allow_email = ($_POST['allow_email'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
    echo $allow_email;
    $register_data = array(
        'username'    => $_POST['username'],
        'password'    => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'   => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'       => $_POST['email'],
        'email_code'  => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime()),
        'allow_email' => $allow_email
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    echo 'You have been registered successfully! Please check your email';
    exit();
```

And this is what is displayed on my site:

1You have been registered successfully! Please check your email

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
kindest regards,
Steven

Comment: `echo $allow_email;` - third line

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
echo $allow_email;
```

It causes the problem. It displays the value of `$allow_email`.

Comment: great! didn't even see that there, must have left it from testing!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Sometimes, we can't detect these small problem while we are focusing something big. It can be easily detected by third eye

Answer (score 2):

On the third line of the snippet you provided you echo out `$allow_email`.

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $allow_email = ($_POST['allow_email'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
    echo $allow_email;
```

Because that obviously has no significance you can remove `echo $allow_email;`.

Comment: great! didn't even see that there, must have left it from testing!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Sometimes it takes an extra set of eyes :P You can mark this as the answer.